# Extract Trigger

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

For trigger created like this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_delete ON Table-A 
FOR DELETE
AS
insert into Table-B           
    values(.......);
```

How could get the name of Table-B, Type of trigger which is DELETE and the action of trigger which is insert?

---

**Edit :**
The code:

```
exec sp_helptext 'trigger name'
```

Returns the definition of trigger.But what if I need to save the items I mentioned above (Table that is affected with trigger firing, Action of trigger and type of trigger) into variables separately?

---

**Edit 2:**
I ran this query to retrieve the trigger name and type of trigger (`delete`)

```
SELECT name, OBJECT_NAME(parent_obj),isdelete = OBJECTPROPERTY( id, 'ExecIsDeleteTrigger') from sysobjects WHERE type = 'TR'
```

And this one to retrieve the name of Table-B :

```
SELECT referenced_entity_name FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies WHERE referencing_id = OBJECT_ID('Tr_delete')
```

May be there is a way to extract the `insert` action of trigger?

Comment: `exec sp_helptext 'tr_delete'`

Comment: Since triggers can contain arbitrarily complex code, there's not going to be something built in that can extract `Table-B` or `insert`. I don't even think there's an easy way to determine which events (e.g. DELETE) that the trigger fires for.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever,So there is no suggested answer for this question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `sys.trigger_events` view](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187322.aspx) to retrieve the list of events for which a trigger fires:

```
WITH cteOrderedTriggerEvents As
(
    SELECT
        object_id,
        type_desc,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (
            PARTITION BY object_id 
            ORDER BY type_desc
        ) As RowNumber
    FROM
        sys.trigger_events
),
cteConcatenatedTriggerEvents As
(
    SELECT
        object_id,
        CAST(type_desc As varchar(50)) As type_desc,
        RowNumber
    FROM
        cteOrderedTriggerEvents
    WHERE
        RowNumber = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        E.object_id,
        CAST(E.type_desc + ', ' + O.type_desc As varchar(50)),
        O.RowNumber
    FROM
        cteConcatenatedTriggerEvents As E
        INNER JOIN cteOrderedTriggerEvents As O
        ON O.object_id = E.object_id
        And O.RowNumber = E.RowNumber + 1
),
cteTriggerEvents As
(
    SELECT
        object_id,
        Max(type_desc) As type_desc
    FROM
        cteConcatenatedTriggerEvents
    GROUP BY
        object_id
)
SELECT
    QUOTENAME(Sc.Name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(Tb.Name) As TableName,
    QUOTENAME(Tr.name) As TriggerName,
    Tr.is_instead_of_trigger,
    Te.type_desc
FROM
    sys.triggers As Tr
    INNER JOIN cteTriggerEvents As Te
    ON Te.object_id = Tr.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.objects As Tb
    ON Tb.object_id = Tr.parent_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas As Sc
    ON Tb.schema_id = Sc.schema_id
ORDER BY
    Sc.name,
    Tb.name,
    Tr.name,
    Te.type_desc
;
```